# Format Azure Virtual Machine Windows 2012 R2

Tags: azure, azure-vm-templates

I have Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter server on MS Azure. I have to format it. Is there a way to do this on Azure or I'll have to create new instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No (unless you have a backup\snapshot), just create a new instance. its fast.

Comment: Ok. By the way, creating new instance is asking to purchase windows license, earlier it was not.

Comment: also read this article which has some techniques to minimize costs while formatting:http://windowsitpro.com/azure/quick-format-azure-virtual-machine-disks

Comment: its not asking for that, its prompting you if you need a license. license was always included in VM cost (by default), but right now you have an easy way to save money and not pay for it if you have your own license. previously it was not possible using the portal. @Gaurav